# What should be the Java object for this JSON String?

Tags: java, json, pojo

```
{"userId":"vincent","favTracks":{"favourite":"15","unFavourite":"121"}}
```

What can be the Java object for the above JSON String?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

Comment: that is a very ambiguous question because json has no complex types, and java does. its a question of how you want to model this data. there are (too) many different answers to answer the question as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to map it. If you're using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), for example, with the default mapping settings, your classes could look something like:

```
class MyObject {
    private String userId;
    private FavTracks favTracks;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public FavTracks getFavTracks() {
        return favTracks;
    }

    public void setFavTracks(FavTracks favTracks) {
        this.favTracks = favTracks;
    }
}

class FavTracks {
    private String favourite;
    private String unFavourite;

    public String getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public void setFavourite(String favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    public String getUnFavourite() {
        return unFavourite;
    }

    public void setUnFavourite(String unFavourite) {
        this.unFavourite = unFavourite;
    }
}
```

One remark: in your current example, the `favourite` and `unFavourite` properties are of a string type. Maybe a numeric type is more suitable?